# RubyMine errors after creating 'Rails application' project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I've downloaded and installed "rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p180.exe", then I installed gems(rubygems-1.6.2 by running 'ruby setup.rb') and the installed rails by running 'gem install rails'.
After doing all this, I've downloaded and installed RubyMine 3.1

In RubyMine I try to create new 'Rails Application' project, in the 'Rails application settings' dialog it shows above installed rub as the Ruby Interpreter, Rails Version says '3.0.5'. Rails Template is empty. 'Preconfigure for selected databases' is unchecked, and also "skip test:unit files' is unchecked.

After clicking ok, it creates some files at the top of the code there is a message "some of the required getms are note attached: sqlite3"( I didn't ask DB, so why sqlite??) anyway I click, on 'attach gems'.

After that I click on play icon, and get below errors. Please help me resolve this issues.  Thanks in advance!

```
------------------------------
C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/kobi/RubymineProjects/deded/script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
from C:/Users/kobi/RubymineProjects/deded/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Users/kobi/RubymineProjects/deded/script/rails:6:in `require'
from C:/Users/kobi/RubymineProjects/deded/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyInstaller for Ruby 1.9.2 doesn't support any other RubyGems version except the one which comes with the RubyInstaller. By updating RubyGems you break your Ruby installation. Please reinstall Ruby into the clean directory and don't update RubyGems.

Also, it looks like sqlite3.dll is missing from your PATH environment. [Download](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070500.zip) it and unpack into RUBY_HOME\bin or c:\windows\system32. Rails needs some database and sqlite is the default.

Some native gem extensions may require DevKit installed, if you have problems installing such gems, [install DevKit](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) first.

Comment: thank you. I reinstalled ruby, and had to install rails framework('gem install rails' otherwise RubyMine wouldn't create RoR project.) and had same error. Then after downloading and putting sqlite dll into path, it started to work. It would be so much better if errors given by ruby were more clear(such as 'dll X is missing')

Answer (score 0):

Try this from console:

```
cd C:/users/kobi/rubymineprojects/deded
bundle install
```

Comment: Didn't help, same errors. (the bundle command itself completed succesfuly)